# ancestor-or-self choosing also sibling of ancestor

Tags: selenium, xpath

I use `ancestor-or-self` in WebDriver.

The result I get is not correct, and I pay attention that WebDriver also choose the (preceding) sibling of my ancestor.

How can I avoid it?

**Edit**

Code example:

```
<div class="model1">
   <div class="ng-hide" id="1">
   <div id="2">
       <form class="model 3">
           <div class="5">
           <div class="model 6">
           <div class="model 7">
              <div class="9">
                 <button id="try1">
                 <button id="try2">
```

Now, I do the next:

```
List<WebElement> lstElm = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[@id="try2"]/ancestor-or-self::*"));
```

When I iterate over `lstElm`, and search if there is an element that it class contains `hide`, I see that my xpath return also the element `<div class="ng-hide" id="1">`. But this element is the **preceding sibling** of it ancestor (and not it ancestor)

Comment: Have you got a short, clear, concise, and understandable example to show us the problem?

Comment: Please provide either the html or xpath. It is not possible to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo in your example, but as written, <div class="ng-hide" id="1"> is an ancestor of <button id="try2">...

Comment: @Erlock: How can I get only div id="2", and not div id="1"?

Answer (score 0):

Contrarily to what you think, the element which starts with `<div class="ng-hide" id="1">` **is an ancestor** of `<button id="try2">`. Look at your HTML and note how `<div class="ng-hide" id="1">` starts but is never closed anywhere:

```
<div class="model1">
   <div class="ng-hide" id="1"> <!-- This is not closed!!! -->
   <div id="2">
       <form class="model 3">
           <div class="5">
           <div class="model 6">
           <div class="model 7">
              <div class="9">
                 <button id="try1">
                 <button id="try2">
```

To get the results you are expecting, you need something like this:

```
<div class="model1">
   <div class="ng-hide" id="1"></div> <!-- The div is closed right away. -->
   <div id="2">
       <form class="model 3">
           <div class="5">
           <div class="model 6">
           <div class="model 7">
              <div class="9">
                 <button id="try1">
                 <button id="try2">
```

With this HTML, `<div class="ng-hide" id="1">` is closed *before* the next `<div>`.